# What is the limiting factor when docker restart slows down with a large number of workers and a short task?

Tags: docker

Expected behavior:

We want to have docker containers perform small jobs. Say we have ten containers and each just sleeps for 5 seconds. We want these to continue to restart quickly. If you have a docker compose with 10 containers defined thusly where each container sleeps for 5 seconds and dies.

```
some-worker1:
  image: some-worker
  build: ./some-worker
  restart: always
```

We expect these containers to restart right away after dying.

Observed behavior:

If you run `watch docker ps`, you notice that the restart time slowly increases. After running for a few minutes, the containers will only restart after a minute. And they will consistently restart after a minute.

Guesses:

I imagine that the docker-engine or whatever restarts the containers has some policy for how quickly to restart them. They begin restarting quickly, so maybe some resource becomes scarce, and docker has to slow the restart speed or as an optimization slows the restart speed, but sets the max at a minute.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this explains it:

"An ever increasing delay (double the previous delay, starting at 100 milliseconds) is added before each restart to prevent flooding the server. This means the daemon will wait for 100 ms, then 200 ms, 400, 800, 1600, and so on until either the on-failure limit is hit, or when you docker stop or docker rm -f the container.

If a container is successfully restarted (the container is started and runs for at least 10 seconds), the delay is reset to its default value of 100 ms."

https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#restart-policies---restart

Comment: This is very helpful. Thank you. Do you know if the running time that docker considers success can be configured? Or is the use case not supported for containers running less than ten seconds?

Comment: It looks like there's no configurable options for this, at least I couldn't find it... is there any time sensitive reason that your container must exit after 5 seconds? if you can make it stay up for more than 10 seconds then you can avoid the restart increment delay.